# Inverting a regex that includes two expressions

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex that matches all lines that either contain no `'t'`s at all, or which contain at least one `'t'` that is not in the sequence `'th'`. I want to invert it, so that it matches only those lines that contain `'th'` but no other `'t'` on its own.

```
^.*?t(?!h).*?$|^[^t]+$
```

Here is a sample input. The expression currents matches all the lines with + sign.

```
thought +1
though -1
without +2
within -2
tenth +3
thoth -3
tents +4
sample +5
thirteenth +6
```

How can I write this expression with a negative lookahead so that it matches only the lines with the - signs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
^(?!.*t[^h]).*th.*$
```

Tested here: http://regex101.com/r/jS5fW8/1